# Update Panel not working in Firefox 2013

Tags: 2013, ajax, updatepanel

Update Panel is not working in SharePoint 2013. It is working in SP2010.
In Internet Explorer, it is working fine but in Firefox, the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be some sort of change in the postback mechanism that's used by SharePoint and ASP.NET in SP2013.

[Here's a solution provided on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650218.aspx)

> In Visual Studio, add a reference to **Microsoft.Practices.SPG.AJAXSupport.dll**. Add a **SafeScriptManager** control to your page and set the **EnableUpdatePanelSupport** flag to **true**. This changes the postback script that is needed for the **UpdatePanel** control to work in a SharePoint environment. The following code demonstrates how to add a **SafeScriptManager** control to a page.

Comment: Can anyone help me to find this Microsoft.Practices.SPG.AJAXSupport.dll . Am struggling to resolve the Sharepoint Updatepanel issue

Comment: This solution is not work on SharePoint 2013. Solution probably for SharePoint 2007