# Using ASP.NET UpdatePanel in custom webpart

Tags: 2013, ajax, updatepanel

I've received the request to add AJAX functionality to an existing custom visual webpart in SP2013 (more precisely: partial refresh of the webpart after clicking a link inside the webpart without reloading the whole page).

I'm totally new to AJAX and came across the **ASP.NET UpdatePanel**.

But it's been said that the UpdatePanel doesn't work with SharePoint OTB causing a full postback. You should install/set a reference to the SharePoint Guidance libraries to use the SafeScriptManager. For example see [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72928/update-panel-not-working-in-firefox-2013) refering to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650218.aspx).

Is this approach still necessary for SP2013, in particular because there is no release of SharePoint Guidance for SP2013 (yet)? Or is there an easier approach to implement a "partial reload" in a custom webpart with the OTB api?

Comment: I've already used UpdatePanel in SharePoint 2010 custom web parts without having to install or configure anything, so I think you should be able to do it in SharePoint 2013 too.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly with an OTB ASP.NET UpdatePanel. I'm just curious: Is the need to use a SafeScriptManager just an approach/best practice from the WSSv3 era that survived until today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently worked on custom RSSViewer webpart. I had originally developed it on my SP 2013 VM. It used AJAX update panel and it worked without any issues. The code for the webpart is provided below:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Syndication;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml;

namespace RSSFeedWebPart.RSSFeedWebPart
{
    [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public class RSSFeedWebPart : WebPart
    {
        UpdatePanel updatePanel;
        Timer timer;
        HtmlTable feedTable;
        private const int const_NumberOfFeedItems = 5;
        private const int const_RereshInterval = 30;
        private int _numberOfFeedItems = const_NumberOfFeedItems;
        private int _rereshInterval = const_RereshInterval;

        [WebBrowsable(true),  
        WebDisplayName("RSS feed url"),
        WebDescription("RSS feed url"),  
        Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),  
        Category("RSS Feed Custom Properties")]  
        public string RSSFeedUrl { get; set; }

        [WebBrowsable(true),
        WebDisplayName("Show publish date"),
        WebDescription("Show publish date"),
        Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
        Category("RSS Feed Custom Properties")]
        public bool IsPublishDate { get; set; }

        [WebBrowsable(true),
        WebDisplayName("Open links in new window"),
        WebDescription("Open links in new window"),
        Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
        Category("RSS Feed Custom Properties")]
        public bool IsOpenInNewWindow { get; set; }

        [WebBrowsable(true),
        WebDisplayName("Number of feed items"),
        WebDescription("Number of feed items"),
        Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
        DefaultValue(const_NumberOfFeedItems),
        Category("RSS Feed Custom Properties")]
        public int NumberOfItems
        {
            get
            {
                return _numberOfFeedItems;
            }
            set
            {
                _numberOfFeedItems = value;
            }
        }

        [WebBrowsable(true),
        WebDisplayName("Feed refresh time (in minutes)"),
        WebDescription("Feed refresh time (in minutes)"),
        Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
        DefaultValue(const_RereshInterval),
        Category("RSS Feed Custom Properties")]
        public int RereshInterval
        {
            get
            {
                return _rereshInterval;
            }
            set
            {
                _rereshInterval = value;
            }
        }

        [WebBrowsable(true),
        WebDisplayName("Feed title style"),
        WebDescription("Enter the optional css style. For example: font-weight:bold; color:red"),
        Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
        Category("RSS Feed Custom Properties")]
        public string FeedTitleStyle { get; set; }

        [WebBrowsable(true),
        WebDisplayName("Item title style"),
        WebDescription("Enter the optional css style. For example: font-weight:bold; color:red"),
        Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
        Category("RSS Feed Custom Properties")]
        public string ItemTitleStyle { get; set; }

        [WebBrowsable(true),
        WebDisplayName("Item publish date style"),
        WebDescription("Enter the optional css style. For example: font-weight:bold; color:red"),
        Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
        Category("RSS Feed Custom Properties")]
        public string ItemPublishDateStyle { get; set; }

        [WebBrowsable(true),
        WebDisplayName("Item summary style"),
        WebDescription("Enter the optional css style. For example: font-weight:bold; color:red"),
        Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
        Category("RSS Feed Custom Properties")]
        public string ItemSummaryStyle { get; set; }

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            feedTable = new HtmlTable();
            updatePanel = new UpdatePanel();
            updatePanel.ID = "updatePanel";
            timer = new Timer()
            {
                ID = "timer",
                Interval = RereshInterval * 60000,
            };
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(timer_Tick);
            this.Controls.Add(timer);
            updatePanel.Triggers.Add(new AsyncPostBackTrigger()
            {
                ControlID = timer.ID,
                EventName = "Tick"
            }
            );
            this.Controls.Add(updatePanel);
            this.Controls.Add(feedTable);                                  
        }

        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            GetFeedData();
        }

        void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void GetFeedData()
        {
            try
            {
                feedTable.Border = 0;
                HtmlTableRow htmlrow;
                HtmlTableCell htmlcell;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(RSSFeedUrl))
                {
                    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(RSSFeedUrl);
                    SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);

                    // Add header row in HTML table
                    htmlrow = new HtmlTableRow();
                    htmlcell = new HtmlTableCell();
                    htmlcell.InnerHtml = feed.Title.Text;                    
                    htmlcell.Style.Value = FeedTitleStyle;
                    htmlrow.Cells.Add(htmlcell);
                    feedTable.Rows.Add(htmlrow);
                    int itemCount = 1;
                    foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
                    {
                        if (itemCount <= NumberOfItems)
                        {
                            itemCount++;
                            htmlrow = new HtmlTableRow();
                            htmlcell = new HtmlTableCell();                            
                            htmlcell.Style.Value = ItemTitleStyle;
                            if (IsOpenInNewWindow)
                                htmlcell.InnerHtml = "<a href=" + item.Id + "  target=\"_blank\">" + item.Title.Text + "</a>";
                            else
                                htmlcell.InnerHtml = "<a href=" + item.Id + ">" + item.Title.Text + "</a>";  
                            htmlrow.Cells.Add(htmlcell);
                            feedTable.Rows.Add(htmlrow);
                            if (IsPublishDate)
                            {
                                htmlrow = new HtmlTableRow();
                                htmlcell = new HtmlTableCell();
                                htmlcell.InnerHtml = item.PublishDate.ToString();
                                htmlcell.Style.Value = ItemPublishDateStyle;
                                htmlrow.Cells.Add(htmlcell);
                                feedTable.Rows.Add(htmlrow);
                            }
                            htmlrow = new HtmlTableRow();
                            htmlcell = new HtmlTableCell();
                            htmlcell.InnerHtml = ((TextSyndicationContent)item.Summary).Text;
                            htmlcell.Style.Value = ItemSummaryStyle;
                            htmlrow.Cells.Add(htmlcell);
                            feedTable.Rows.Add(htmlrow);                           
                        }
                    }
                }

                updatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(feedTable);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log exception
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Perhaps this will help you in creating the custom webpart you want. For more information see my blog post:

http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.in/2013/11/sharepoint-rss-viewer-webpart-for-wss.html

Comment: Did you check whether you webpart is not causing any trouble when using it together with the OOTB project summary webpart of SP2013? Because when I try your code I face the problem that the timeline of the project summary webpart is added another time each the timer is ticking so when a postback is performed.

Comment: Haven't checked that

Comment: Same problem of @André  here